# Covariance of two independent random variable Proof

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, expected-value, joint-distribution

Let X and Y be two independent random variables. Then $\sigma_{XY} = 0$.

Proof: $ Let \ $f(x,y)$ \ be\ their \ joint \ distribution \ formula. \ Then \ \\ \sigma_{XY} = E[(X-\mu_X)\cdot(Y-\mu_Y)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x-\mu_x)\cdot(y-\mu_y)\cdot f(x,y)\ dx \ dy\ \\ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x-\mu_x)\cdot g(x)[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(y-\mu_y)\cdot h(y)\ dy] \ dx \\  = E(x-\mu_x)\cdot E(y-\mu_y) \\ = [E(x)-\mu_x]\cdot[E(y)-\mu_y] \\ = [\mu_x- \mu_x] \cdot[\mu_y- \mu_y] \\ = 0. \\ where \ g(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) \ dy \ and \ h(Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) \ dx $

I split $f(x,y)$ to $g(x) \cdot h(y)$ by the definition of independent events in the first integral.

I tried to prove this property in that manner. Did i made some mistake or is my proof correct?

Comment: The first integrand should be $(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)f(x,y)$, start from there and see how you go

Comment: i forgot to write $f(x,y)$ in first integral.  I will correct it.

Comment: Your proof is incomplete in the sense that it only works for a pair $(X,Y)$ that has a probability density function.

Comment: This proof should not go through, because the assertion is false: it is possible for $\sigma_{XY}$ to be undefined or infinite.  It does not have to be zero.